# Google Mobile Friendly test shows "other error" for resource loads

Tags: google, googlebot-mobile

I get the error "Couldn't load 23 page resources" when doing the mobile friendly test at

https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly

However, the error message is (the rather unfriendly) "Other error."

When I visit the site in Chrome using Developer Tools and setting the device toolbar to "Responsive," it works fine with no errors, and when I go the Google Search Console and do Crawl->Fetch As Google, I get no errors.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable.  It MIGHT be possible to find an issue on your site that MIGHT be the cause of the error.  But it's probably not going to be much help for anyone else.

Comment: If you want help with the issue, I believe it would be easier on Google's Webmaster Central Help forum, because this will likely require lots of analyzing your site and asking you questions about lots of stuff before reaching any conclusion. //  If it gets resolved, you could then edit this question if needed and answer it yourself to make it useful for other people.

Comment: ... Or a different webmasters' forum.  But I can mention two reasons why WMC is the right choice: access to Google through Top Contributors and Rising Stars, and I know there's "no" SEO scum there. (They exist, but get stopped before they cause any harm.)

Comment: Very good - I will try that and report back here if I get some good answers.

Comment: Scott, I use both tools and there are indeed discrepancies in the number of issues and how they fetch. I prefer GSC's native UI, because your site is verified and it knows your site a little better than MFT. That said, MFT is still worth examining. Check for issues like blocked resources and heavy images and font files. I'd take care of any GSC issues first. For a list of possible (non-robots.txt related) "other errors," check out their documentation: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6352293?hl=en . Good luck!

Comment: @HenryVisotski: It looks like it was intermittent.  The "other error" applies to timeouts (tested) so it's reasonable that it would apply when Googlebot decides to not even try as well ("temporarily unreachable" in Fetch as Google contains these two cases).  But if that's the case, then Googlebot decided to not try any single resource at all which sounds kind of implausible.  // I also can't find a list of error statuses on that help doc.  (That's why I had to do a test.)

Comment: You are correct @OskarSkog - the CSS and JS errors were gone on my last test (although they seem to come and go).  But I do still get a "redirection error" on my YouTube videos like  http://www.youtube.com/embed/FN2S-y1XX8M?rel=0.  Even adding &html5=1 doesn't seem to fix it - any ideas on that?

Comment: @OskarSkog That makes sense. Timeouts as "other errors" - Google definitely omitted quite a bit from their documentation...

Comment: are your scripts blocked against crawling? robots.txt?

Comment: The "other error" doesn't mean that it is blocked by robots.txt.  Google specifically tells you if something is blocked by robots.txt.    Other errors are something else and Gooogle isn't saying.   I'm seeing it for some of the images in my page.  They are small images and Google has permission to fetch them.  See this screenshot from the URL inspection tool: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBqao.png

Answer (score 13):

I had 6 instances of "other errors" (4 images and 2 stylesheets) and continually hitting the refresh button didn't help. here's what I think finally fixed it for me:

1. I switched 2 of the images from relative to absolute paths. that fixed both of those.
2. I removed the type="text/css" from my css head tags that called the 2 stylesheets. so, they now have only the rel and the href -- like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.example.com/styles.css">`. that fixed the remaining 4 errors. (apparently the remaining 2 images were being called in the stylesheets.)

Comment: removing text/css fixed it for us. thanks!

Comment: Absolute path fixed this issue, thanks.

Comment: Absolute paths fixed it for me, too. I wonder if it is the combination with robots.txt and GoogleBot incorrectly processing it?

Comment: Absolute path for fonts fixes those. After that, the error occurs intermittently with in general a few requests failing. Running on CloudFront CDN, 40 requests, mobile pagespeed 80+.

Comment: I doubt that chaning `text/css` or absolute paths fix anything, it's more likely that you just trigger a re-crawling, which randomly "went better". It looks like the core issue is performance and timing as Google just *somtimes* rejects *some* assets (see support thread in @GreatBlakes's answer). I have resources with absolute paths right next to each other and there is no rhyme or reason why some produce "Other error". Also keep in mind that the internal GSC crawler and the manual testing tool are not the same thing.

Comment: My GoDaddy Wordpress has all resource URLs configured to come from a CDN. I suspect that the different domain may be causing the issue, and an absolute URL may fix it

Comment: It looks like Google downranks text/css as well as relative paths.
This is no problem for average websites but when you have a lot of google crawler traffic it will start "skipping" content once quotas are hit.
Making the important parts non text/css and absolute helped a lot on my end. thanks.

Comment: Website stored at GoDaddy (not Wordpress!), I tested several times all the combinations of your suggestions, only the relative->absolute path is necessary to resolve the error.

Answer (score 12):

[According to this support thread](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/4425254?hl=en), "Other error" may be that Googlebot reached the limit of the number of requests it is willing to make to a server to prevent it from overwhelming the website with requests (AKA "Crawl Budget").

There was not a definitive answer, but that appears to be the response. If this is true, I wish the "error" message was changed to something like "Rate Limit Reached"...

Comment: I had about 40 small images on my page.  Reduced this number by using the "sprite image" method.  It fixed the Mobile Friendly Test/Other Error problem.

Answer (score 3):

"load 23 page resources" that sounds like your page has a Lot of resources to load.

The mobile tester doesn't like 'heavy' pages.

There are many ways this mimics what it might be like loading it a real mobile device that might have a unstable data connection.

Make the page 'lighter' - loading less 'crud' & the page will load quicker, and hence more 'friendly'.

Comment: A similar helpful answer for status 'Other error' : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/JwBSfBlZYas

Comment: What is the suggested limit? It doesn't seem to load *any* resources except for `index.html`.

Comment: Disagree: 23 resources is not a lot.

Comment: this is not a lot of resources at all

Answer (score 1):

Check your robots.txt to see if it's blocking GoogleBot from any required to load the page.

For example, you could possibly have a CSS script in the `<head>` that calls a URL that's disallowed in your robots.txt

Comment: What if I have no `robots.txt`?

Comment: If you have no `robots.txt`, then nothing is being blocked - so that isn't an issue.

Comment: Our website (https://mrosupply.com) had a separate subdomain (called static.*) served via AWS Cloudfront from a AWS S3 bucket. Digging though the Cloudfront logs it was found that GoogleBot was receiving a 503 LambdaEdge error upon visiting https://static.mrosupply.com/robots.txt, because the file was inexistent. Simply adding a robots.txt file to the S3 bucket that the subdomain was pointing to, solved the issue for us.

Comment: the tester will clearly reference the robot.txt file and link to it, if it is the case of the block in my experience.  Also sometime your host will pop in a default robots.txt if you delete yours, so always check your url/robots.txt to see if in fact you do have one