# Page Resources Couldn't be Loaded” on GSC even after clearing everything on robots.txt

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, robots.txt, mobile-friendly-tool

Google Search Console and Mobile-Friendly Test both give me the following two warnings for my Wordpress based website:

- Content wider than screen
- Clickable elements too close together

The screenshot that these sites provide of my website completely looks broken as if no CSS was applied.

Many solutions to this problem seem to identify the robots.txt file as the culprit, as some users may be blocking google bot from accessing the resource files such as stylesheet or JavaScript.

My case was different. The following state is how my robots.txt file looks like, and I still get the same warning messages none the less. I am an SEO framework user, so I created my own static version of the robots.txt.

```
User-agent: *    
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://*****
```

There are also suggestions that the weight (heaviness) of the website is to be blamed. In my case, I have only a few JavaScript files that are mainly in charge of some very light tasks such as carousel, slide-down answers for faq, and the menu button for the nav-menu.

I tried many things including switching themes and surprisingly, the same issue happens even for the WordPress official theme "twenty-seventeen" and also "twenty-nineteen" or the blank version of the "Underscores" theme, but not when I used my original theme that doesn't have any JavaScript files.

Do I really have to go the route of NOT using JavaScript at all, and strictly only use css to style my website, or can it be that there are other things to look at??

Along with the two warnings, I also almost always get "Page Loading Issue" on the test results. Could it be that this is a server speed related issue? I am located in Japan at the moment, and my website is also targeted mainly for Japanese, but I am using a SiteGround server and not a Japanese server. I am well aware that this is giving me a speed-related issue in general for my website, but is this also affecting the results of the above-mentioned google tests?

Comment: Do you get "other error" for those resources in that tool?   A new answer to [Google Mobile Friendly test shows “other error” for resource loads](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107967/google-mobile-friendly-test-shows-other-error-for-resource-loads) says it could be a rate limit as to how much Googlebot is willing to fetch.

Comment: Are the resources from different domains? If so, they are subject to the robots.txt files on those domains and not yours. The tools can also have intermittent issues with resources as they have quite a short timeout period so that you see results in a reasonable time. The real crawler has a longer one.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, thank you for those who tried to pull me out of this situation.

After trying different things with no success, (Except for switching the wordpress theme that uses NO javascript, which always magically solves the problem for some reason), I finally ended up looking at the plugin called "SG Optimizer" which was privaded to me by SiteGround.

Long story short, I activated this plugin, and inside the plugin, under the tab called "FRONTEND OPTIMIZATION", I enabled "Minify JavaScript Files".
And all of a sudden, I get "Page is mobile friendly" with zero error.

If I deactivate the plugin, my website goes back to "NOT mobile friendly".
If I activate the plugin and leave all the settings as default, I also get "NOT mobile friendly".

So I guess the solution for me was to minify the javascript files.

Thank you again for those who tryied to help.
I hope my experience will save someone some time in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation, but it seems the SiteGround Optimizer has been updated since ray's answer in 2019.

Now you must go to: `SG Optimizer/Frontend/Javascript` and then enable: `"combine javascript files"`.  After I did this, everything worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar your problems
So, at first you have to scan site in pages peed insights and then, look that with css and js unused, and disable on this page or site.
If you use WordPress, you can use the Asset CleenUp to disable every file in your pages.
That's it
Also This plug-in minify css and js file and cache it, that so good for fast load your site
I hope to my experience will help you
Bye

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).